# Java - Sending Multiple Mails in Parallel

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I have a requirement to send multiple mails in parallel. Lets say I have 10 person emails (my actual requirement have around 100's of recipients). For sending mails to all those 10 people, I need to hit multiple services for collecting information based on the emailId and it will take a lot of time. Having said my email trigger service is totally isolated function, and I don't have any constraint in the order of mail triggering.

Firstly I used the normal way like as shown below, but it is triggering in sequential order and taking more time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> emails = Lists.newArrayList();
    emails.add("first-person@gmail.com");
    emails.add("second-person@gmail.com");
    emails.add("third-person@gmail.com");
    emails.add("fourth-person@gmail.com");
    emails.add("fifth-person@gmail.com");
    emails.add("sixth-person@gmail.com");
    emails.add("seventh-person@gmail.com");
    emails.add("eighth-person@gmail.com");
    :
    :

    for(String email: emails) {
        sendMail(email);
    }
}
private static void sendMail(final String email) {
    // function will call many other services for getting the information required for sending the email
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("Sending Mail for:"+email);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Secondly I heard abt Java8 parallel streams (I am very much new to this), So thought of using it like as shown below. It seems a to trigger the mails a little more faster than the sequential order

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> emails = Lists.newArrayList();
    emails.add("first-person@gmail.com");
    emails.add("second-person@gmail.com");
    emails.add("third-person@gmail.com");
    emails.add("fourth-person@gmail.com");
    emails.add("fifth-person@gmail.com");
    emails.add("sixth-person@gmail.com");
    emails.add("seventh-person@gmail.com");
    emails.add("eighth-person@gmail.com");
    :
    :

    emails.stream().parallel().forEach(email -> {
        sendMail(email);
    });
}
private static void sendMail(final String email) {
    // function will call many other services for getting the information required for sending the email
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("Sending Mail for:"+email);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me whether my approach of using Java8 parallel stream is correct for this approach

Comment: `CompletableFuture` seems like a good fit for your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not. The way you use it will resolve to non-concurrent anyway.

What you want is to have an `ExecutorService` which you can pass your mail sending logic to.

```
ExecutorService mailService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
for (String email : emails) {
    mailService.submit(() -> sendMail(email));
}
```

EDIT:

Since it came up in the comments:
You can just as well send them one by one with pretty much the same construct, but:

```
ExecutorService mailService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

This will call `sendMail` one by one.
The difference to doing it in a straight loop like `emails.forEach(m -> sendMail(m))` is that the sending itself is happening in another thread, meaning the main thread doesn't block on calls to `sendMail` and is free to do other things.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, can you tell me in what scenario we can use the Java8 parallel stream

Comment: Right now my requirement is non sequential but lets say If client says if I needs to maintain the order of mailing then how we can achieve it using `ExecutorService `

Comment: @AlexMan, I haven't been able to find a good reason for using `stream().parallel()` in production-ready large systems. Reliance on shared thread pool means you have to be absolutely clear which task relies on which, and in large systems this is very hard. In smaller exhibit apps, however, there is a case for using parallel streams, because each submission to common pool is easier to track.

Comment: @AlexMan Well if you want to retain the order, you can only send one at a time, you can use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`. I don't really see why you wouldn't just loop the original list in that case.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I feel like `stream().parallel()` is saying "you can do that in parallel if you want, but I don't really care and am not counting on it".

Comment: @daniu ooh then for sequential order we can use normal for loop instead of `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` right. Both does the same right

Comment: @daniu, it's not though. Parallel execution on parallel stream is mandatory, and great deal of design went into making it work. What's missing is the ability to use executors other than common pool.

Comment: @AlexMan, single thread executor does equal work, but not the same, because it does so *on different thread*, and it would have a different unit of work compared to a `for-loop` (Task vs iteration).